# Meta for developers dashboard, message_template_status_update's POST Request verification failing

Tags: facebook, webhooks, whatsapp

i am stuck with a weird problem, in the Meta for developers dashboard, i have subscribed to two webhooks, which are messages and message_template_status_update webhooks, My callback URL is is verified, and messages webhooks works just fine, it gets verified (i followed the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#create-endpoint) but when it comes to message_template_status_update webhook, i get the request but it is not getting verified.

I tried with different callback URLs, but it did not work.
what am i missing??? Hoping someone could help me on this issue

I am using php laravel for the verification, the sample code is as below

```
  if($request->hasHeader('x-hub-signature-256'))
  {
   $sha_sig = $request->header('x-hub-signature-256');
   $sha_sig = str_replace('sha256=','',$sha_sig);

   $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', json_encode($request->all()), env('META_APP_SECRET'));

   if($sha_sig == $signature)
   {
       //payload verified, proceed with other things
   }
   else
   {
      //Payload not verified
   }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"i get the request but it is not getting verified"_ - meaning what, exactly?

Comment: hi @CBroe, what i meant was, let's say i create a template and it gets approved, i get a POST request from meta to my callback url, now the issue is, i am not able to verify the payload, i create a sha256 key from the payload and the app secret and compare to the sha256 key i get from meta (which resides in headers called x-hub-signature-256) that is the verification process mentioned in the docs, but both are not matching, funny thing is, i am not facing this issue with messages webhook.

Comment: So show us how you are verifying the signature then.

Comment: sorry for missing that, i have added the sample code.

Comment: `json_encode($request->all())` - that is likely to result in a different representation of the data, than what Facebook used. You should get the _raw_ request body, and calculate the signature based on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe, it worked, instead of doing json_encode($request->all()), i used $request->getContent() to create SHA256 hash, and it worked. i still don't get why json_encode one validated correctly with messages webhook's payload but not with message_template_status_update webhook payload.

Comment: `json_encode` has a lot of different options on how _exactly_ the data will be encoded - such as, should unicode characters be inserted directly, or escaped as `\uXXXX`, should slashes be escaped, etc. So you will probably not match the exact encoding mechanism Facebook used, and if the data differs between the two subscriptions in one of the ways that would be relevant, then you can easily end up with it working for one of them, but not the other.